# Mac Terminal Find and Open command

Tags: macos, terminal

I would like to be able to use the terminal command find to search for files, (easy enough) but then I want the containing folders to be automatically opened. Is there a way to do this in one line of script?

This is the argument that I have written but it still tries to open the file rather that simply the containing folder.

`find ~/ -iname "*unbroken*" -execdir open {} ";"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try

```
find . -iname "*unbroken*" -execdir open . ";"
```

or (not tested)

```
find ~/ -iname "*unbroken*" -execdir open ~/ ";"
```

Comment: @brad thank u for accepting my answer, but i think Ken's answer is more correct than mine. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
find ~/ -iname "*unbroken*" -exec open -R {} ";"
```

The `-R` option to `open` tells it to reveal the file in the Finder. Not only will that open the containing folder, it will select the item.